# Which fonts are used in various bill receipts ? For example what is the font of the attached text image cropped from a receipt?

Tags: font-identification

[image]

Which fonts are used in various bill receipts ? For example what is the font of the attached text image cropped from a receipt ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is a standard but usually they use condenced types to save space.

Something like Ristretto would be a good example. You can [try it here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/ristretto-pro)[image]